# Recursive System

Tags: stata, recursive-model

Considering a two equation model:

Equation 1

```
Trunk=f(Headroom)
```

In the first step I regress the first equation to get predicted values of Trunk.

Equation 2

```
Price=f(Trunk_hat, Displacement)
```

I have performed this in Stata, however I also want a mathematical derivation of this procedure. What is the method to go about it?

Comment: These sorts of things come up a lot in econometrics -- [Simultaneous_equations model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_equations_model)

Comment: The manual entry for a command in Stata (the .pdf or the book, _not_ the help-file, i.e. what you get when you type `help something`) usually contains a "methods and formulas" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the matrix algebra performed for OLS. The beta estimates in OLS are: $(X'X)^{-1} X'Y$; that multiplied by your $X$ vector will get you the first stage fitted values.

Comment: Is there any way other than the matrix form?